# SwiftUI Text Editor with a floating label

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swift-extensions, swiftui-texteditor

I am trying to style a **Text Editor** in **SwiftUI** to look like a Material Design element. Currently, I'm struggling with the floating label.
I cannot figure out how to capture the **editing state** of Text Editor.
This is the code of the app:

```
struct FloatingTextEditor: View {
let textFieldHeight: CGFloat = 168
private let placeHolderText: String
@Binding var text: String
@State private var isEditing = false
public init(placeHolder: String,
            text: Binding<String>) {
    self._text = text
    self.placeHolderText = placeHolder
}
var shouldPlaceHolderMove: Bool {
    isEditing || (text.count != 0)
}
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
        TextEditor(text: $text)
            .onTapGesture {
            isEditing = true
        }
            .padding()
            .frame(height: textFieldHeight)
            .paragraph()
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                        .stroke(Color.medium, lineWidth: 1))
            .animation(.linear)
        
        Text(placeHolderText)
        .foregroundColor(Color.medium)
            .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
        .padding(shouldPlaceHolderMove ?
                 EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading:15, bottom: (textFieldHeight+30), trailing: 0) :
                 EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading:15, bottom: (textFieldHeight-10), trailing: 0))
            .scaleEffect(shouldPlaceHolderMove ? 1.0 : 0.8)
        .animation(.linear)
    }
}}
```

Essentially I need help with figuring out then the Text Editor is tapped out of.

This is the design of it for reference:
[Text Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAuwh.png)

Comment: sorry, but I just don't understand your question here. Could you explain a bit more, what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity, when you tap on the text editor I want the label to float up and when you tap out or on another element for the label to return to its original position. Hope this makes it a bit more clear

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are already handling when it gets clicked originally, just failing to handle when it loses focus. You need to use something like onCommit as well as onTapGesture.